# Selecting the 2nd MultiIndex Level of Pandas DataFrame as an Indexer

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, multi-index

I have a pandas DataFrame with multiindex where I want to select all rows between 11am and 1pm.

```
import pandas as pd

data = [
    ('Jack', '2020-01-01 10:00:00', 12),
    ('Jack', '2020-01-01 11:00:00', 13),
    ('Jack', '2020-01-01 12:00:00', 14),
    ('Jack', '2020-01-01 13:00:00', 15),
    ('Jack', '2020-01-01 14:00:00', 16),
    ('Ryan', '2020-01-01 10:00:00', 34),
    ('Ryan', '2020-01-01 11:00:00', 35),
    ('Ryan', '2020-01-01 12:00:00', 36),
    ('Ryan', '2020-01-01 13:00:00', 37),
    ('Ryan', '2020-01-01 14:00:00', 38),
]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['name', 'datetime', 'score']).set_index(['name','datetime'])
```

```
#                           score
# name datetime                  
# Jack 2020-01-01 10:00:00     12
#      2020-01-01 11:00:00     13
#      2020-01-01 12:00:00     14
#      2020-01-01 13:00:00     15
#      2020-01-01 14:00:00     16
# Ryan 2020-01-01 10:00:00     34
#      2020-01-01 11:00:00     35
#      2020-01-01 12:00:00     36
#      2020-01-01 13:00:00     37
#      2020-01-01 14:00:00     38
```

My current solution requires converting all the multiindex to regular columns, converting the `datetime` column to an indexer which is then used to select the desired rows. The multiindex is then rebuilt.

```
df = df.reset_index()
indexer = pd.DatetimeIndex(df['datetime'])
df = df.loc[indexer.indexer_between_time('11:00', '13:00')].set_index(['name', 'datetime'])
```

```
#                           score
# name datetime                  
# Jack 2020-01-01 11:00:00     13
#      2020-01-01 12:00:00     14
#      2020-01-01 13:00:00     15
# Ryan 2020-01-01 11:00:00     35
#      2020-01-01 12:00:00     36
#      2020-01-01 13:00:00     37
```

**Question:** Is it possible to directly use the 2nd level of the multiindex as the indexer, thus avoiding having to `reset_index` and `set_index`?

Or is there an even better method to achieve the filtering of rows between 2 different times?

*I am using Python 3.7.4 and pandas 0.25.1. Willing to upgrade to newer versions if they allow better solutions*

Answer (score 2):

You can use the index directly with [`get_level_values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.get_level_values.html) and [`pd.IndexSlice`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.IndexSlice.html):

```
indexer = (pd.DatetimeIndex(df.index.get_level_values('datetime'))
           .indexer_between_time('11:00', '13:00'))
df.loc[pd.IndexSlice[:, df.index.get_level_values('datetime')[indexer]], :]
```

---

```
                          score
name datetime                  
Jack 2020-01-01 11:00:00     13
     2020-01-01 12:00:00     14
     2020-01-01 13:00:00     15
Ryan 2020-01-01 11:00:00     35
     2020-01-01 12:00:00     36
     2020-01-01 13:00:00     37
```

Comment: Why did you have to put the outer parenthesis outside of `pd.DatetimeIndex`? Is it for splitting the code statement into 2 lines?

Answer (score 1):

```
df.loc[(slice(None),slice('2020-01-01 11:00:00','2020-01-01 13:00:00')),:]
```

output:

```
                          score
name datetime                  
Jack 2020-01-01 11:00:00     13
     2020-01-01 12:00:00     14
     2020-01-01 13:00:00     15
Ryan 2020-01-01 11:00:00     35
     2020-01-01 12:00:00     36
     2020-01-01 13:00:00     37
```